# How do I read abstract programming information

Tags: c

I had a test yesterday and I found myself having to understand something I had no knowledge about.

Please see the following page:

```
declaration-list:
  declaration
  declaration-list declaration 
declaration-specifiers:
  storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
  type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
  type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt 
storage-class specifier: one of
  auto register static extern typedef 
type specifier: one of
  void char short int long float double signed
  unsigned struct-or-union-specifier enum-specifier typedef-name 
type-qualifier: one of
  const volatile 
struct-or-union-specifier:
  struct-or-union identifieropt { struct-declaration-list }
  struct-or-union identifier 
struct-or-union: one of
  struct union 
struct-declaration-list:
  struct declaration
  struct-declaration-list struct declaration 
init-declarator-list:
  init-declarator
  init-declarator-list, init-declarator 
init-declarator:
  declarator
  declarator = initializer 
struct-declaration:
  specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-list; 
specifier-qualifier-list:
  type-specifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
  type-qualifier specifier-qualifier-listopt 
struct-declarator-list:
  struct-declarator
  struct-declarator-list , struct-declarator 
struct-declarator:
  declarator
  declaratoropt : constant-expression 
enum-specifier:
  enum identifieropt { enumerator-list }
  enum identifier
```

This is from the book "The C Programming Language" by Brian W. Kernighan
Dennis M. Ritchie but I saw it on the internet and on many other books.

I tried googling it but frankly, I have no Idea how is it called so I couldn't find any relevant information. Our professors have never tought us to read it and I now believe it's extremely important to know how to read it.

I'm looking for reference to guides or a short explanation on how to approach it.

I apologize if that's a repost but I couldn't find any related post.

Comment: This is a formal context-free grammar notation known as [Backus–Naur form (BNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

Comment: Actually it's not really BNF, but some other notation (e.g. "one of" is not BNF, and it would be `::=` instead of simply `:`).

Comment: it is called : formal grammar notation

Comment: Right. Not a strict BNF (if at all). As aforementioned `::=` and the *choice* symbols are not the same as in classical BNF (which are `|` in BNF, but a newline and indentation here and "one of" ). But the idea is the same. If you understand one, you understand the other.

Comment: It is similar to [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

Comment: For a simple example of a grammar notation, check the [www.json.org](http://www.json.org) page. It describes the grammar graphically on the left side of the page, and using some sort of a grammar notation on the right side. So it starts something like: "an `object` can either be `{}` or `{ members }`". Then it needs to define `members`: `members` can either be `pair`, or `pair, members`, which is a recursive way of saying that `members` can be a single `pair`, or several `pair`s separated by a comma.

Comment: It's intended to be intuitive. The first block says that a declaration list is either a declaration or a declaration list followed by a declaration. Which basically means that a declaration list is a non-empty sequence of declarations.

Comment: And things with the `opt` subscript are optional items in the grammar.

Comment: If you want to write C code that uses such a grammar (as opposed to just reading the grammar to learn about C), look into [yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) and its relatives (byacc, bison)

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I've coded for 25+ years and never had to know this :)

Comment: Thank you everyone!

It may not be necessary when it comes to developing something but on tests it can be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called the syntax notation. It is described in [C11 6.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.1):

> 1. In the syntax notation used in this clause, syntactic categories (nonterminals) are indicated by *italic type*, and literal words and character set members (terminals) by **bold type**. A colon (:) following a nonterminal introduces its definition. Alternative definitions are listed on separate lines, except when prefaced by the words ''one of''. An optional symbol is indicated by the subscript <sub>opt</sub>, so that
>
>    **{** *expression*<sub>opt</sub> **}**
>
>    indicates an optional expression enclosed in braces.

So, to take the first non-terminal as an example:

> *declaration-list*:
>          *declaration*
>          *declaration-list declaration*

means that a *declaration-list* is a single *declaration*, or alternatively a *declaration-list* followed by a single *declaration* (i.e. it would define itself recursively).

By the way, these *declaration-lists* are the old and long obsolete way how function parameters were typed in C:

```
some_function(a, b)
    int a;
    double b;
{
    printf("a = %d, b = %f\n", a, b);
}
```

The `int a; double b;` part is the optional *declaration-list*, and `double b;` is a single *declaration*. So the declaration-list is defined recursively as being a declaration list that is of one declaration, or a declaration list that is followed by a declaration.

---

To actually internalize meaning to these syntactic constructs, you'd better read the [C11 standard draft n1570 online](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) or the [PDF version](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Note also, that the grammar just gives the syntax of a C program, but the constraints and semantics of the C program are written in text.

Comment: Thanks! It was what I was looking for.

I found the syntax that this book uses:
[The syntax of C in Backus-Naur Form](https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The first definition...

```
declaration-list:
    declaration
    declaration-list declaration
```

...can be read as: "A declaration-list is either a declaration or a declaration-list followed by a declaration."

This recursive definition allows for the following as examples of a declaration-list:

- declaration
- declaration declaration
- declaration declaration declaration
- etc.

The full grammar definition will contain additional rules describing what makes up a valid declaration, and so on.